# Angular Jasmine tests error - $injector is not defined

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, karma-jasmine

Using Karma Im back filling tests on a project (someone else wrote the angular app - I have the 'pleasure')...

Project written in coffeescript.

I have the following jasmine test:

```
'use strict'

describe 'module:file:controller', () ->
  $controller = null
  $scope = null
  $state = null
  $stateParams = null
  Page = null
  File = null

  beforeEach (module 'forge')

  beforeEach inject(($rootScope, _$controller_, _$state_, _$stateParams_, _Page_, _File_) ->
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $state = _$state_
    $stateParams = _$stateParams_
    Page = _Page_
    File = _File_
    $controller = _$controller_
  )

  describe 'init', () ->
    controller = null

    beforeEach () ->
      $state = {}
      $stateParams = {}
      controller = $controller('fileController', {$scope: $scope, $state: $state, $stateParams: $stateParams, Page: Page, File: File})

    it 'should set page title to File', () ->
      spyOn(Page, 'title')

      expect(Page.title).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'Files'

    it 'should do something with delete', () ->
      spyOn(Page, 'addAlert')

      $scope.delete(1)

      expect(Page.addAlert).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Here is the controller:

```
forge.controller 'fileController', ($scope, $state, $stateParams, Page, File) ->

  # Inject base controller
  $injector.invoke BaseController, this, { $scope: $scope, Factory: File }

  # Set page title
  Page.title 'Files'

  console.log $stateParams
  console.log $state

  # Delete
  $scope.delete = (id) ->

    Page.addAlert 'success', '[TEST] Deleting file...'

    console.log $stateParams
    console.log $state

  # Delegate actions
  switch $stateParams.action
    when 'delete' then $scope.delete $stateParams.id
```

I have a bunch of unit test running fine. The application is built using grunt and all code is compiled into /dist/assets/js/app.js.

My karma config:

```
module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set

    files: [
      '../../dist/assets/js/app.js'
      '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'unit/**/**.test.coffee'
      '../module/**/test/unit/**/*.unit.coffee'
    ]

    preprocessors:
      'unit/**/**.test.coffee': ['coffee']
      '../module/**/test/unit/**/*.unit.coffee': ['coffee']

    frameworks: ['jasmine']

    reporters: ['progress']

    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari']

    logLevel: 'ERROR'

    jasmineNodeOpts:
      onComplete: null
      isVerbose: false
      showColors: true
      includeStackTrace: false
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
```

When I run the tests I receive:

```
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) module:file:controller init should set page title to File FAILED
  ReferenceError: $injector is not defined
  at new <anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:75397:3)
  at Object.instantiate (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:14449:14)
  at /Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:19700:28
  at /Users/usr1/repos/proj/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2170:12
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/src/module/file/test/unit/controller/file-controller.unit.js:25:27)
  Expected spy title to have been called with [ 'Files' ] but it was never called.
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/src/module/file/test/unit/controller/file-controller.unit.js:35:33)
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) module:file:controller init should do something with delete FAILED
  ReferenceError: $injector is not defined
  at new <anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:75397:3)
  at Object.instantiate (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:14449:14)
  at /Users/usr1/repos/proj/dist/assets/js/forge.js:19700:28
  at /Users/usr1/repos/proj/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2170:12
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/src/module/file/test/unit/controller/file-controller.unit.js:25:27)
TypeError: $scope.delete is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usr1/repos/proj/src/module/file/test/unit/controller/file-controller.unit.js:39:23)
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.11.3): Executed 63 of 63 (2 FAILED) (1.155 secs / 1.134 secs)
```

Checked all the paths and that the controllers are presentin teh built app.js file.

At a loss now as to why this message persists and any pointers would be great.

Comment: `forge.controller` should have `$injector` dependency in function

Comment: It's probably easier to run your tests against the unminified/uncombined code so that you don't have to dig through 75000 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application was minified - this would prevent this working.

[angular injector docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#injection-function-annotation)